# What to do with misclicked flags?

Tags: discussion, chat, flags

A user flagged [this chat post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/272306#272306) as offensive or spam. Like 95% of flags, that post actually isn't offensive or spam. Unlike 95% of flags, however, it pointed to a real problem: the very next post, with a mildly disturbing computer simulated image.

I'm asked to judge whether the post is offensive or not. *Technically* it isn't, so if I say "no" I'll reduce the weight of future flags from this user. *Practically*, it is -- you just had to see the context to see the problem; something the flag interface doesn't provide.

- It wouldn't make sense to say "yes," because I'd contribute to removing the wrong message.
- It wouldn't make sense to say "no," because there's a real problem there and the user should be rewarded for it.
- It wouldn't make sense to do nothing, because it feels wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure we have any "weight of future flags" in chat...

Comment: @Marc I do know Jeff did look into that. I connected the flag reviewing stuff with it, especially now that apparently it's been brought to the main sites too.

Comment: Yes, q&a has a *very subtle* flag weighting based on prior history. This only affects **order** - we don't ignore any flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do nothing and get the user to flag the image (if that's what they intended) and deal with *that* flag.

This assumes that you have some knowledge (via another chat window perhaps?) of who apparently miss-clicked when flagging.

If you don't then you are stuck at step one which is to do nothing on the (incorrect) flag.

Comment: How would you suggest I contact the (rightly) anonymous flagger? :) PS: I did flag the image.

Comment: @radp - Ah, you spotted the flaw in my argument.